# Rails adds extra empty element to end of ordered list when iterating through array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of 4 comments I want to iterate into an ordered list to create 4 lines of comments.

My ERB partial:

```
<ol>
  <% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c.body %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

However, when it is being rendered on the page it looks as follows:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz
4. Foobar
5.
```

It seems to be adding an extra empty element at the end of the loop cycle.

What seems to be the issue with how I'm iterating through the array?

Comment: The way you're iterating looks fine. Is it possible you have an extra blank comment at the end of your list for some reason. You should be able to check that from the rails console. If your not sure how to do that, let me know and I can explain further

Comment: if you have no validation to save an empty comment, it's possible.

Comment: I have 4 records as should be expected.

`2.3.0 :011 > @post.comments.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 4], ["commentable_type", "Post"]]
 => 4`

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found out my answer.

I failed to mention in my question that I also had a `form_for` a new comment on the same page that listed comments.

On my `Post` controller, I had it set up as `@comment = @post.comments.new` on that action. Which, in turn created an empty, unsaved comment on that view for `@post`. So, on that action I changed it to a generic `@comment = Comment.new` and then manually passed in the `id`s that I needed to make the association in the end. I don't know if that's the "best" way, but it is the way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how many comments you have associated with the post like below,

```
@post.comments.count
```

There will be 5 records. Delete the last one and add validation in comment model by below,

```
validates_presence_of :body
```

That should keep it from producing blank records. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: There are 4 records

`2.3.0 :011 > @post.comments.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 4], ["commentable_type", "Post"]]
 => 4`

Comment: Any java-script added which causing it to add one more li, if it's an open source git can you share link ? otherwise remove the html element and execute it as below 
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
  ######<%= c.body %>######
<% end %>
This will let you know if loop is executing more time or not.

Comment: There is no sort of javascript anywhere. It's a plain Rails app.

If you want to check the source: https://github.com/antonio97b/rails5-Forum/tree/create-comments-model. Standard setup. Clone it, create the database and migrate, run the seed file and then you'll have to manually add some comments to a post of your choosing.

Comment: I went ahead and `destroy_all` Comments in the database, and it still append the list with an empty `1. ` on the page. It shouldn't even be executing that partial because it is inside `<%= @post.comments.any? %>` which returns `false` inside the console. it should be executing the if block..

Comment: Have you tried this 
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %> 
######<%= c.body %>###### 
<% end %> 
with out the ol tags

Comment: Yes, it just appends `5. #######`. See my edit in the above comment. it's still executing the `if` block as if it is `true` even if there are no comments in `@post`

Comment: One very not good way you can add condition like below 
<% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
    <% unless c.body.blank? %>
       <li><%= c.body %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
But not recommended.

Comment: I think I see my issue, Muaaz Rafi. I believe the form I have on the same page is creating a yet unsaved comment and causing it count as an empty comment when trying to iterate.

Comment: Did you add validation on the model comment ?